# Choosing between 2 middleware in express

Tags: node.js, express

Hello i am creating a validation middleware but the problem is i have 2 types to the same endpoint so i created two schema for each.

All i want to do is when type is **somthing** pass through **middleware_a** esle return **middleware_b**

here is my idea but its not working

```
const middlewareStrategy = (req,res,next) => {
if(req.params.type === "Something"){
   return custom_middleware(schemas.A_body);
}
return custom_middleware(schemas.B_body);};
```

A_Body here is just validation schema.

Comment: Can't you just check the `type` inside `custom_middleware` and select the correct schema there?

Comment: Yes i can but i just want the code to be more cleaner and thanks for ur comment.@charlietfl

Comment: So that is less complicated . Why would it not be the cleanest way?

Comment: What i think is that this code is more readable and easy to debug

Comment: When you say not working, what is the error\issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to tell eactly what you're trying to do because you don't show the actual middleware code, but you can dynamically select a middleware a couple of different ways.

**Dynamically call the desired processing function**

```
const middlewareStrategy = (req,res,next) => {
    const schema = req.params.type === "Something" ? schemas.A_body : schemas.B_body;
    bodyStrategy(schema, req, res, next);
};
```

In this middleware, you're dynamically calling a bodyStrategy function that takes the schema and res, res, next so it can act as middleware, but will know the schema.

**Create a middleware that sets the schema on the `req` object**

```
const middlewareStrategy = (req,res,next) => {
    req.schema = req.params.type === "Something" ? schemas.A_body : schemas.B_body;
    next();
};
```

Then, use it like this:

```
// this sets req.schema to be used by later middleware
app.use(middlewareStrategy);
```

Then, you can use another middleware that expects to find the `req.schema` property to do its job:

```
// this middleware uses req.schema
app.use(customMiddleware);
```

---

If this isn't exactly what you were looking for, then please include the code of your actual middleware so we can see what we're really aiming for.

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what am looking for. @jfriend00